# How to bypass object NULL reference check

Tags: c#

I have below code.

```
                     var cfg = _cfgUtil.GetCCfg(addr.Cnt, li.txDte);
                        if (cfg != null && cfg.Isabc)
                        {
                           await <some operation>
                        }
```

it is failing in second line

```
if (cfg != null && cfg.Isabc)
```

what Im not getting is , how to bypass this NUll reference check

exact error Im getting is :

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

Comment: Why do you think that is the line where the Exception is thrown? There are sometimes misleading reasons about lines of code like source not matching the executing code (due to changes or building optimized output). If it really is being thrown here it could also be that `Isabc` is more than a simple getter and that this is throwing the NRE.

Comment: I'm confused - are you getting that error _with_ the null reference check? If so then the error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: The answer in the [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1260204) is pretty much a "how to troubleshoot a NRE", a guidebook if you will. Use the advice in that answer to figure out what is causing the NRE in your code

Comment: yes , it worked , actually , I made the correct change but forgot to save and recompile . thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

I would say your `Isabc` is what has the `null` value.

That would need checking also, `cfg.Isabc != null`

Alternatively, if you are using a newish version of C# the folowing would work, without needing separate checks.

```
// Option A:
if(cfg != null && cfg.Isabc != null)
{
    //...
}

// Option B:
if(cfg?.Isabc is not null)
{
    //...
}
```

This all assumes `Isabc` is of type `bool?`, since normally a `bool` wouldn't be `null` and other types wouldn't work that way in the if statement.